# Android studio не видит genymotion устройство

Tags: android-studio, genymotion, android

Здравствуйте.

Установил genymotion для android studio. Но при запуске компиляции в списке не появляется виртуальное устройство.

[image]

Comment: В genymotion поставь в настройках adb, который использует студия.

Answer (score 3):

Если он не видит в *adb*, можно по старинке перекидывать файлы:

найдите в папке проекта `app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`, это и будет ваш *апк*, перемещайте *апк* в окошко *genymotion*, он его поставит — пользуйтесь.

Если в указанной директории у вас нет папки apk (и соответственно файла app-debug.apk), в верхнем меню Android Studio нажмите Build->Build APK.

Answer (score 3):

Знаю что тема уже мертва, но все же, еще надо зайти в настройки Genymotion и выставить ADB -> Use custom Android SDK tools -> Путь к SDK от Android studio. После у меня заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Если установил только саму Genymotion, то не будет распознавать виртуальное устройство в android studio. Нужно обязательно устанавливать [плагин Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/) для android studio.

Answer (score 0):

[Посмотрите здесь](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1083577/genymotion-perestal-zapuskat-ustroystva-android-w7).

Comment: @kot197676, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.